# Как эффективно затереть данные

Tags: c#, файлы, инспекция-кода, файловая-система

**Задача:** повредить файл, для обеспечения невозможности его чтения. (И удачного восстановления если его удалить **программным способом**, на той же машине (тем способом, доступным среднестатистическому пользователю гугл поиска))

Скрытие факта затирания файла - не интересует.
Объем файлов и их количество - любое (можно вычислить по ходу)

Вид хранилища - любой (можно вычислить по ходу)

Вид файлов люб...

Какой алгоритм будет считать в себе скорость и эффективность?

Первое что пришло в голову, открыть файл потоком, и пройтись с неким шагом "понатыкивая" нулевые байты. Что можно улучшить?

*Код на C#:*

```
private void FileDamage(Stream stream)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                const int upper = 1000;
                var step = stream.Length / upper;
                if (step == 0) step = 1;
                for (long l = 0; l < upper; l++)
                {
                    stream.Seek(step, SeekOrigin.Current);
                    stream.WriteByte(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

P. S. Не охото полностью затерать файл (а то и неоднократно).
Вопрос состоит в том, что является достаточным в данном случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря, что за файл (данные внутри файла) и что для вас значит "невозможность восстановления" и сильно зависит от размера.

- Для начала можно почитать [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Уничтожение_данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) - это стандарты уничтожения данных
- В принципе самый лучший способ - это просто на низком уровне записать весь файл битовым паттерном `"01010101"` и потом второй раз `"10101010"` - тогда никто никогда ваши данные не восстановит. Даже из жесткого диска.
- Если это запускаемый бинарник - можно попробовать "проредить" его "нулями" с шагом меньше 50
- Если это текст или картинка, то удалять надо все байты или это вполне неплохо может быть восстановлено логически или алгоритмически.

Comment: Размер файла косвено зависит от его типа. А тип в теории может быть любой (можно конечно сделать несколько алгоритмов и выберать на лету)

Comment: @Opossum Тогда лучше просто перетереть весь файл 1 раз нулями или паттернами, что я написал. Тогда ваш файл уже не восстановят. Писать несколько алгоритмов стоит только если на 100% уверены, что всегда со 100% уверенностью сможете определить, что за файл вы затираете.

Comment: @Opossum Примите ответ, если он кажется вам правильным. Спасибо

Comment: Насчет лучшего способа, полностью переписать все данные файла - это конечно надежно, но что насчёт скорости. Ладно там картинка или текст, а что насчет видео, которое может и 10+ gb весить, а может и не одно.

Comment: @Opossum Если вы не уничтожите ключевые кадры и данные в файле, тогда восстановить его можно за несколько часов. Дело в том, что в видео есть опорные кадры, которые показывают всю картинку и последующие кадры показывают только разницу. При наличии даже нескольких ключевых кадров - можно восстановить очень-очень много. В принципе - это будте долго, согласен.

Comment: @Opossum Однако если у вас SSD или 10k HDD, тогда это будет не настолько долго. )

Comment: Оптимезация железом это уже другой вопрос, сейчас интересует именно алгоритм

Comment: А имеет ли смысл затирать его на SSD? Там же по сути в новое свободное место запишется шаблон стирания, а на старое просто связь утратится, пока не будет выполнен TRIM.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Возможно, утверждать не буду. Но я больше говорил конечно о HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Помню, в легендарном пакете [Norton Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Utilities) были утилиты Wipe, которые затирали данные многократным проходом, с записью разных данных (на радость параноикам).

Также вспоминается Уотергейтский скандал, когда запись на магнитофонной кассете была *случайно* стёрта секретаршей. И как потом эту запись пытались [восстановить](https://kiwibyrd.org/2013/12/05/207/).

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что даже стёртую запись можно (попытаться) восстановить. Более того, кроме магнитных носителей есть и оптические, и флэш...

В общем, всё не так просто.

---

Если бы я писал утилиту для затирания данных, я сделал бы минимум два прохода: один раз **все** биты записываются нулями, другой раз - единичками. Это, на мой дилетантский взгляд, даст большую степень уверенности, что не останется никаких наводок магнитных полей по краям дорожки (хотя на ленте, хоть на диске).

Это, как мне кажется, справедливо и для магнитных накопителей, и для оптических, и для флэш-памяти (кроме SSD).

SSD - особый разговор. Для уменьшения износа ячеек контроллер может переносить данные на реже используемые ячейки. В итоге, как я понимаю, на накопителе одни и те же данные могут быть *физически* продублированы. Старая копия затрётся при записи новых данных, но до того момента она есть. И когда мы, казалось бы, затрём свой файл, данные всё равно присутствуют на драйве в предыдущей области. И их можно извлечь, имхо.

Полагаю, тут поможет только *полное* затирание *всего* объёма накопителя. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Так, ладно уточним задачу. Интересует избежание именно программного востановления, без извлечения диска и ковыряния в магнитных полях в поисках остатков.

Comment: @Opossum Тогда поверх записывай любую информацию. На HDD это перезапишет информацию без возможности восстановления, а на SSD старую информацию со временем очистит TRIM(который можно запустить принудительно, если не ошибаюсь).